# Can't install Mrtg on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: apt, package-management, kernel, python, dpkg

I can't install MRGT-2.17.4 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS  Text appear Error below ?

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
mrtg is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libart-2.0-2 libcdr-0.0-0 libcmis-0.4-4 libmspub-0.0-0 liborcus-0.6-0
  libvisio-0.0-0 libwpd-0.9-9 libwpg-0.2-2 libwps-0.2-2
  linux-headers-3.13.0-85 linux-headers-3.13.0-85-generic
  linux-image-3.13.0-85-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-85-generic
  python-pexpect python-renderpm python-reportlab python-reportlab-accel
  thunderbird-locale-en thunderbird-locale-en-gb thunderbird-locale-en-us
  xfonts-mathml

Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up pbis-open (8.2.0.2969) ...
Error: /opt/pbis/sbin/lwsmd --start-as-daemon --disable-autostart --loglevel debug returned 127 (aborting this script)
/var/lib/dpkg/info/pbis-open.postinst: 74: /var/lib/dpkg/info/pbis-open.postinst: /opt/pbis/sbin/lwsmd: not found

dpkg: error processing package pbis-open (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 pbis-open
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: `mrgt` is installed.

Comment: Line 4 says: 'mrtg is already the newest version.' Sure you can't install it? Also, the original command is missing.

Comment: Yes,i'm sure ,but i check directory  mrtg already  disappear any file .

Answer (score 0):

As the output says, MRTG is already installed:

> mrtg is already the newest version.

---

However, the package `pbis-open` errored during installation.

One way that might fix this is the command `sudo apt install --reinstall pbis-open`

---

Also, you have a lot of orphaned packages installed (dependencies that were installed but are not longer required)

You can remove these with: `sudo apt autoremove`